# barman configuration via command line

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I'm using barman in a virtual environment and I wanted to make barman use a specific configuration file I created before, ending with `.conf`.
The problem is, that the command

```
barman -c CONFIG
```

does not work and I don't know why. When I enter the command, I get a "usage" export of the command.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by this "usage export"?

Comment: It only says how to use the command with its options.